# Pandas: how to use a function dictionary to assign a column value based on calculations between other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

With the following Pandas DataFrame, how would I make a new column, "spend" for example, based on a function name in another column?

Example Dataset

```
  cost method  metric  rate  total planned
0        CPMV    2000   100           1000
1        CPMV    4000   100           1000
2        Flat       0     0           1000
3        Flat       0     0              0
4        Free       1     2              3
```

I need to calculate cost based on the cost method.

- CPMV: *df.metric* / 1000 * *df.rate*
- Flat: *df.total planned* / variableLength <-- a variable
- Free: 0 <-- return just 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by first setting up a function dictionary. Keys will be the names and values the calculation. Then, using a lambda inside an apply function, you can determine which key's function you would like to use by selecting the cost method for reference.

1. Make a function that accepts your dataframe and column names as arguments.
2. Within the function, write a dictionary using the cost method name you want functions to be associated with as the key. The values are the column name arguments.
3. Create a selector for the cost method.
4. Use get to return the function value or "not in dict".
5. Use a lalmbda function inside apply to use the method.

> Accounting for a flight_length of 0, using a safe_div function will return the total_planned instead of an error.

```
# make safe_div
def safe_div(x,y):
    if y == 0:
        return x
    return x / y

# write the dictionary
def applyCalculateSpend (df_name, cost_method_col, metric_col, rate_col, total_planned_col):
    calculations = {
            'CPMV'  : df_name[metric_col] / 1000 * df_name[rate_col],
            'Flat'  : safe_div(df_name[total_planned_col], flight_week_diff),
            'Free'  : 0
            }
    df_method = df_name[cost_method_col]
    return calculations.get(df_method, "not in dict")

# call the function inside a lambda
test_df['spend'] = test_df.apply(lambda row: applyCalculateSpend(
row,
cost_method_col='cost method',
metric_col='metric',
rate_col='rate',
total_planned_col='total planned'), axis = 1)

  cost method  metric  rate  total planned  spend
0        CPMV    2000   100           1000  200.0
1        CPMV    4000   100           1000  400.0
2        Flat       0     0           1000  500.0
3        Flat       0     0              0    0.0
4        Free       1     2              3    0.0
```